# Efficient Cypher Update Query to Capture "Discovered" Relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have an analytics use case where I'm piling a bunch of nodes into Neo4j with different sets of properties. They come from different systems and different tables, but there are shared properties across various of the node types (the information has been through an ETL process).

What I want to be able to do is query the graph for all of the nodes with a property of, say, customer_id and find all of the other nodes that have the property with the same value and create an edge between them, capturing any arbitrary matches.

I label the nodes during ingest based upon the source tables, I've created auto indexes for the linking properties, and I've added a label to the nodes with the common property so that I can put label indexes on them, but I haven't stumbled across the right syntax to efficiently make all the connections.

I'd like to keep this in Cypher because it's something where the customer may ask for different views, so we might be inventing new edges based upon other kinds of matches (so "discovered" relationships) rather than having a full schema in mind going in, then be able to use the discovered edges to perform traversals that answer questions you couldn't have asked before the association.

My test suite has 9 million nodes and many of the attempts I've made so far have performed poorly.

This is one naive attempt that actually works against a small number of nodes, but doesn't scale very well. How would you approach the problem? I think that there is some way to do this efficiently using collections, but I have not worked out that syntax yet.

Here is one naive attempt at it that works on a small set of nodes, but does not scale well.

`using periodic commit 100
match 
  (a:CUST_ID_NODES), (b:CUST_ID_NODES)
where
  a.customer_id=b.customer_id
create unique
  (a)-[r:CUSTOMER_ID {customer_id: a.customer_id}]-(b);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the label `:CUST_ID_NODES` group nodes that can be joined on property `.customer_id`? If so you had better create the relationships on ingest instead. It sounds like you define indexes for potential future views to create, but I don't see that this is any cheaper or easier than to create all the views you know about from the start.

If you still want to do it in cypher, here are some thoughts. Your current query executes as: match all customer id nodes as `a`; for each `a`, match all customer id nodes as `b`; filter on shared `.customer_id`. If you have 100 000 customer id nodes, that's 10 000 000 000 results to filter on shared property, and **none of this uses indexing**. A first improvement of your query could be to start with each distinct value for `.customer_id` and look up the nodes that have that value from an index. Assuming you have an index like

```
CREATE INDEX ON :CUST_ID_NODES(customer_id)
```

do this to get the nodes per customer_id

```
MATCH (a:CUST_ID_NODES)
WITH DISTINCT a.customer_id as id
MATCH (a:CUST_ID_NODES {customer_id:id})
// You can continue with flat (id, a) rows, or collect a per id 
// and do stuff in a FOREACH loop, something like:
WITH id, collect(a) as aa
MERGE (common {customer_id:id})
FOREACH (a IN aa | MERGE a-[:COMMON]->common)
```

Now the query gets the distinct list of values to look up nodes on, and this time when getting the nodes the label index is used.

Then there are different ways to connect these nodes. You relate every node to every other that shares its id. The best representation depends on how you're going to query the graph later. If the idea is that nodes that share `customer_id` represent the same thing and can therefore be merged, the easiest way is probably to represent the shared-ness as a new node and either relate the sharing nodes to it, or merge properties and relationships from the sharing nodes into the new node. But I'm still not convinced there is a benefit to doing this in cypher instead of during ETL and ingestion–it seems like just the thing for a Transform step in Talend or Pentaho.

Comment: Thanks, jjaderberg. I agree that doing this on ingest would be best, but it assumes that we understand all the ways that this could be queried, which we don't - or at least we don't want to restrict it, so we'll ultimately want to add new relationships as we go. Your sample query looks good, I will work with it and report back.

Comment: I think you have me on the right track. If I'm not mistaken, the query you described above does indeed create a new node, or hyperedge node, when it merges into _common_. I have this working for the most part, but I'm missing something in the final merge. When I give _common_ a new label I can query it afterward, but the :COMMON relationship does not get created. I'll paste what I have in a new reply - I've overstuffed this text box.

Comment: @Vramin If one of the answers given fit your question you can accept it, if not you can add a comment or clarify your question. If you have follow up questions that are not clarifications its better to post them separately; if you post a follow up question as an answer (forum style) no one can really answer you.

Comment: I've not participated in Stackoverflow so much, and I'm trying to do what you're describing, but the interface is not really cooperating with me. I've tried your style of query and it's almost there (it creates new nodes for _common_), but the _merge_ in the last _foreach_ is not creating any new edges. Can you help me understand how that's supposed to work?

Comment: I gave you credit for the answer. I'll ask a fresh one to figure out where my query is going south.

Comment: If you run the query as it stands it should connect all nodes to each other (the `MERGE` clause should match all the nodes sharing `customer_id`) but if you add a new label, say `:COMMON` to the merged node, it should relate all of them to a new, common node. Does [this console](http://console.neo4j.org/r/apvuop) help?

Comment: Great, asking a new question will help keep the problem specific, and if you can setup sample data to illustrate the question in a console as above that will help clarify the problem even more.

Comment: You absolutely earned the credit. The console was a great help, and I got the query working. Not sure where I was mistyping it, but it's all good now and won't require any additional questions. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If nodes a and b have the same customer_id, are you supposed to create relationships between them in both directions? This does not seem to be a very efficient thing to want to do. I think you can very simply avoid creating these relationships.

What I suggest is that:

1. You give all nodes with the customer_id property the same label, say 'Customer'. A node can have multiple labels, so you can legally add this extra label to nodes that already have labels.
2. Create an index based on that label and property:

   CREATE INDEX ON :Customer(customer_id);

Then, whenever you need to find all the nodes with the same customer_id, you can do this efficiently:

```
MATCH (c:Customer {customer_id:{id}}) RETURN c;
```

Comment: Thanks, cybersam. I have indeed created the index on the customer_id field for the CUST_ID_NODES label, so I should be able to efficiently get to the customer identifiers. However, we want to be able to query the graph based upon various traversals, so creating the relationships is key. The CUST_ID_NODES label groups together all nodes from all sources that exhibit this property, but the relationships would now let me traverse the types without necessarily needing to know the customer ID (start from a product and find customers who bought it, or find friends of customers who bought, etc.).